# products not showing in product view page django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

i created a function to view products in products view page i tried so many times but cant find any one help me please

here is my code

`views.py`:

```py
    
def product_view(request,cate_slug,prod_slug):
    if (Category.objects.filter(slug=cate_slug, status=0)):
        if (Products.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug, status=0)):
            product = Products.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug, status=0)
            contex = {
                'product':product,
            } 
        else:
            messages.warning(request,"product  not found") 
            return redirect("collection")
    else:
        messages.error(request,"something went wrong")
        return redirect("collection")
    return render(request,"product_view.html",contex)
```

`urls.py`:

```py
path('collection/<str:cate_slug>/<str:prod_slug>',views.product_view,name="product"),
```

`product view.html`:

```html
{% extends 'auth.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}


<h1> {{ products.name }} </h1>


{% endblock %}
```

i just want to see product detils in product view html page any one help me because i am new to django

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `product`, not `products`.

Comment: hi the problem is in my views.py i want to display products in django eccomerce website all other things are ok also i passed contex with my template template is loading correctly but not showing any details in product view html page

Comment: i changed into product still not getting brother

Comment: please provide models

Comment: brother how can i modify question because when i add like comment there is text limit

Comment: i checked brother its not working for me brother

Answer (score 1):

In views:

```
def product_view(request,cate_slug,prod_slug):
    if (Category.objects.filter(slug=cate_slug, status=0)):
        if (Products.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug, status=0)):
            product = Products.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug, status=0)
          
        else:
            messages.warning(request,"product  not found") 
            return redirect("collection")
    else:
        messages.error(request,"something went wrong")
        return redirect("collection")
    return render(request,"product_view.html",{'product':product}) #I have removed context from if statement and added directly here.
```

And in your templates:

```
{{product.name}} #Use this only, when you want to display single field only.
```

**OR**

```
{% for prod in product %} #Use this only, when you want to display all fields on template
   {{prod.name}}
   #Add remaining fields
{% endfor %}
```

And see if it solves

Comment: i tried this too brother still i didnt get brother can you please tell my views.py is correct brother ?

Comment: @Asim are you getting any error?

Comment: no brother i am not getting any error server is comptely working fine

Comment: {% for prod in product %} 
   {{ prod.product_name }}
   {{ prod.selling_price }}
   
{% endfor %}    when i run like this i got all products now but  when i run like this nothing is showing {{ product.product_name }}

Comment: try to use this inside a tag. <div>{{product.product_name}}</div>

Comment: it works bro but all products have same name brother now all products have same name showing i product view.html pagw how can i overcome this can you please tell

Comment: first product name is repeting to all others brother

Comment: show me that. take a screnshot and paste it in question

Comment: post as a new question ??

Comment: please see in database, if you entered same name for all products

Comment: not brother every item is different

Comment: actually in my first product name in databse that was repeting to other products that is going brother

Comment: There is something wrong with your views

Comment: brother i found one error

Comment: hi  product = Products.objects.filter(slug=prod_slug, status=0).first()  when i use first() that was displaying first product name to all but when i remove first its not showing anything brother

Comment: when i remove first name is not showing showing when havibg first() its repeting first name to every other products

Comment: I posted as new question brother can you please check

Answer (score 0):

You are using `{{product.name}}` which is wrong. products (actually `product` based on your view) is a queryset and it doesnt have a `name`. Instead first change your queryset name to a more distinquishable `products`, then use this:

```
{% for product in products %}
{{ product.name }}
```

Comment: i used loop to print still not working brother

Comment: Use the correct queryset name . If you pass it as product in your view use i.e for x in product

Comment: yes i typed as i in product the i .name  brother

Comment: brother my function is written correctly or any syntax error with function ?

Comment: Cant really say with only this part of the code provide additionail info. If your view is correct the above solution should work .

Comment: actually no error while loading template but this thing only not working brother can u please what additional info brother ?